# Set separate background colors for each linked calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

Is there a way to set the background colors for days that have events that are specific to different Google calendars? I.e.: I would like all days with events from calendar 1 to have a blue background and all days with events from calendar 2 to have a green background. I know how to change background colors for all events together, but not how to separate them by Google calendar. My current setup with qTip2 and Fullcalendar:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(c){
(function() {
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

var tooltip = $('<div/>').qtip({
    id: 'fullcalendar',
    prerender: true,
    content: {
        text: ' ',
        title: ' ',
        button: true
    },
    events: {
        render: function(event, api) {
            var elem = api.elements.bgiframe;
        }
    },
    position: {
        my: 'bottom center',
        at: 'top center',
        target: 'event',
        viewport: $(window),
        adjust: {
            mouse: false,
            scroll: true,
            method: 'shift',
            resize: true
        }
    },
    show: {
        modal: {
            on: false,
            blur: true,
            stealfocus: false
            }
        },
    hide: false, 
    style: {
        classes: 'qtip-bootstrap qtip-shadow qtip-contact',
        border: {
            radius: 2
        }
    }
}).qtip('api');

$('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({

    eventSources: ["https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/emailaddress1%40gmail.com/public/basic",
        "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic"],

    header: {
        left: 'title',
        center: '',
        right: 'today prev,next'
    },

    selectable: true,
    eventClick: function(data, event, view) {
        var title = '<h5 style="margin:0;padding:0;">'+data.title+'</h5>'; 
        var content = '<p style="margin:0;padding:2px;"><b>Start:</b> '+data.start+'<br />' + 
            (data.end && '<p style="margin:0;padding:2px;"><b>End:</b> '+data.end+'</p>' || '');

        tooltip.set({
            'content.title': title,
            'content.text': content
        })
        .reposition(event).show(event);
    },
    dayClick: function() { tooltip.hide() },

    eventResizeStart: true,
    eventDragStart: false,
    viewDisplay: function() { tooltip.hide() }

});
}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

**Javascript:**

```
eventSources: [{
    url:"https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/email_address%40gmail.com/public/basic",
    className: 'organizationevents'
    },
    {
    url:"http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic",
    className: 'holidaysevents'
    }]
```

**CSS:**

```
/*  Colors for events  */
.organizationevents {background:#15BAD3;color:#fff;}
.holidaysevents {background:#9D25F8;color:#fff;}
```

Answer (score 0):

from my experience i have not used google feeds but i think you can get the events before, to a server side aplication, separate the feed into diferent feeds and then using this:

```
var mygooglefeeds = {
                    googlefeedcolorblack: {            
                         url:urltogooglefeedserverside,
                         type: 'POST',                              
                         data:{'googlefeedflag':'black'}, //you don´t actually need this but, you could wrap this multifeed array in a function and use this flag to get the different feed using the same function, your choice, just ignore this line. 
                         cache: false,              
                         color: '#000000', // Its here that you manage the color for this specific events
                         textColor: 'white'//and text color                            
                                        },
                  googlefeedcoloryellow: {            
                     url:urltogooglefeedserverside,
                     type: 'POST',                              
                     data:{'googlefeedflag':'yellow'}, //you don´t actually need this but, you could wrap this multifeed array in a function and use this flag to get the different feed using the same function, your choice, just ignore this line. 
                     cache: false,              
                     color: 'yellow', // Its here that you manage the color for this specific events
                     textColor: 'white'//and text color                            
                                    }  

 }
```

Then using

```
 ...
 eventSources: [mygooglefeeds.mygooglefeedsblack,mygooglefeeds.mygooglefeedsyellow],
 ...
```

you will get the diferent colors for each type of event.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. While this works, I went ahead and used classes for more styling options, instead.